# Use componentDidMount variables from event functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to access a variable created in the componentDidMount method. Whats the best way to do it?

```
componentDidMount() {
    var x = "hello";
}

bye() {
    x = "bye";
}

render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.bye}>)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [React's state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { x: "" };
    this.bye = this.bye.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ x: "hello" });
  }

  bye() {
    this.setState({ x: "bye" });
  }

  render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.bye}>{this.state.x}</div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: But I really need to set the variable at componentDidMount() because it's an object that depends on DOM elements

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: strange, I'm getting TypeError: this.setState is not a function(…) at componentDidMount() I think it's because I'm doing that inside a callback, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `this` (or `state`, see Fabian's answer. Depends on what you want to achieve)

---

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.x = "hello";
}

bye() {
    this.x = "bye";
}

render() {
    return (<div onClick={this.bye}>)
}
```